# How to decode base64 string as HTML content in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert my encoded base64 HTML content from an attribute and place it in the HTML content using XLST, hope somebody can help.

I have this string:

```
<p><b>Hello!</b><span>This is a span</span></p>
```

And this is the base64 encoded value:

```
PHA+PGI+SGVsbG8hPC9iPjxzcGFuPlRoaXMgaXMgYSBzcGFuPC9zcGFuPjwvcD4=
```

The XML data looks like this:

```
<Data Get="True">
    <Result TextFlow="PHA+PGI+SGVsbG8hPC9iPjxzcGFuPlRoaXMgaXMgYSBzcGFuPC9zcGFuPjwvcD4=">
        </Result>
</Data>
```

My last attempt was using [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/4mt/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.dp.xs.doc/extensionfunctions147.htm):

```
fn:cast($XML/Data/Result/@TextFlow,'xs:base64Binary','xs:String',false())

That code send this error:
Unknown function - Name and number or arguments do not match any function signature in the static context.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Base64 conversion is not something I would normally recommend doing in XSLT; bit-twiddling construction of characters is not something XSLT will do well. I'd suggest you call an extension function which does that conversion. Unfortunately the semi-standard EXSLT extension set doesn't include that operation, so you'll probably have to find or write it yourself, then work with your XSLT processor's API to register the function so your stylesheet can call it.

Comment: You certainly could write it in pure XSLT, though it would be rather convoluted, even if you at least know the encoding for the bytestream was always UTF-8 (getting a string from base 64 is really getting a stream of bytes from base 64, and then getting a string from that, and that second step depends on encoding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in capability in XSLT to do this.

Coming soon is the EXPath binary module:

http://expath.org/spec/binary

The bin:decode-string() function is what you need. We've got an implementation of this for Saxon but it's not integrated into the product yet. Meanwhile there is the extension function saxon:base64BinaryToString which is essentially the same:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/base64Binary-to-string

and which is available in Saxon-PE or higher.

Both functions take an argument of type xs:base64Binary; to convert a string in base64 to a value of this type, you use the constructor function xs:base64Binary(string). This requires XSLT 2.0 of course.

If your (decoded) string contains markup, then to copy it to the serialized HTML output you will need to use the deprecated disable-output-escaping="yes" option.

**UPDATE (April 2019)**

Recent releases of Saxon (the current release is 9.9) include the EXPath binary module as standard in Saxon-PE and higher editions.